# Selected string in email (file location in directory) - locate with applescript

Tags: applescript

How would I use applescript to find a file location in the finder from a text string in an email or document?

For example: Someone emails or sends me a word document with a directory path to a document and I select the path... How would I use applescript to find the document in the "Finder" from the selected text string?

I'm using this to get the file by hard coding the path...

```
set theFile to ("filePath.ext" as POSIX file)
tell application "Finder"
    if (exists theFile) then
        select theFile
        activate
    else
        display alert "File " & theFile & " does not exist"
    end if
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go and build an **Automator Service**. Set the service' input to `Text` and `in every Application`. This gets the currently selected text from any application and passes it to the next configured action.

The next Automator action should be a `run Applescript` workflow step. Fill it with

```
on run {input, parameters}
    -- in case that multiple lines are selected
    set allLinesList to paragraphs of (first item of input)

    -- for future needs: output only valid file paths
    set validFilePaths to {}

    -- walking through the lines and try to reveal the file in Finder
    repeat with aLine in allLinesList
        try
            set targetAlias to POSIX file aLine as alias
            tell application "Finder" to reveal targetAlias
            set end of validFilePaths to {}
            -- commented out, needed for debugging only:
            --on error errstr
            --  display dialog errstr
        end try
    end repeat

    -- give valid paths only to the next action
    return validFilePaths
end run
```

If you like you can use this AppleScript as a filter because it passes only valid file paths to the next action.

Maybe you need some corrections depending on your needs. I.e. you may want to delete spaces in front and at the end of your selected string.

Save it as i.e. *Open in Finder* and each time you have selected text inside an application you find the Service *Open in Finder* in the context menu.

Cheers, Michael / Hamburg

Comment: Hey Michael - I tried the code but it's giving me an error:  "Syntax Error  Can't make paragraph of item 1 into type reference." It's giving me the error on the line: "set allLinesList to paragraphs of (first item of input)

Answer (score 0):

If I change your code to the following it works for me...

```
on run {input, parameters}
-- in case that multiple lines are selected
set allLinesList to input

-- for future needs: output only valid file paths
set validFilePaths to {}

-- walking through the lines and try to reveal the file in Finder
repeat with aLine in allLinesList
    try
        set targetAlias to POSIX file aLine as alias
        tell application "Finder" to reveal targetAlias
        set end of validFilePaths to {}
        -- commented out, needed for debugging only:
        --on error errstr
        --  display dialog errstr
    end try
end repeat

-- give valid paths only to the next action
return validFilePaths
```

end run

Comment: Ah, great news :-) In my test environment everything worked and with multiple lines selected Automator got one string containing with multiple lines in input. That's why I added the `paragraphs of (first item of input)` to get all lines. Good job that you found the solution!